# json parsing from models django

Tags: django, json, model

I've found some strange behaviour with python, and I don't get why.

This is how I create items and lists:

```
def createItemJson(self,id,url):
    ret={}
    ret['id']=id
    ret['url']=url
    return ret


def createListJson(self,i):
    ret_l = []
    for i in range(0,i,1):
        ret_l.append(self.createItemJson(i, i))
    return ret_l
```

And this is the output of a list of 3 elements:

```
[{'url': 0, 'id': 0}, {'url': 1, 'id': 1}, {'url': 2, 'id': 2}]
```

If I take this string and I do in shell A:

```
for v in data
```

I can print the 3 objects. N.B.`len(data)` is 3.

Now I store this data in the db as textfield (is it correct?).
When I retrieve the object I get `len` with value **63**.

Basically Django sees it as a string. What can I do? I tried to do json.load but it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no JSON in the example you show. You have a Python dictionary. If you then "store it in a textfield" (note it would have been helpful to show exactly how you are doing that) you have presumably just dumped it as a string into that field. It's still not JSON, it's now a string representation of a Python dict, which isn't quite the same thing. `json.load` will "not work" (once again, exact error message would have been helpful) becaase it's not JSON.

You could try using `json.dumps(my_dict)` before storing it in the database, and `json.loads()` on the way out. Alternatively, use one of the many JSONField implementations you can probably find on a quick Google search.

Comment: i used a json field and it works.
I didn't get how i should convert the string to a correct json to be able to store it in a textField.

Comment: As I said above, use `json.dumps()`.

Comment: "Seem not to work" is not helpful. Exactly what happens? Exactly what are you trying? Do you get an error?

Comment: i tried it yesterday. the problem was this Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 2). i don't remember exactly. i've to revert the project and try it out.